# can i add views to overlays in android maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlays

Is there a way to add views to ItemizedOverlays in android maps? If there is a way please tell me how to.. thank you..

When ever i tap on a marker i want to display its info with images, text and buttons.. I tried many answers in this community, but they all do not match my requirement. So i want to add a view with images, text and buttons to the overlay so that it will work good even when the maps are zoomed or moved..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in onTap method.

```
   protected boolean onTap(final int index) {
    this.index=index;
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    final AlertDialog dial=dialog.create();
    dial.show();
    dial.setContentView(R.layout.showoverlay);
    Window win=dial.getWindow();
    TextView tv=(TextView)win.findViewById(R.id.tvLayTitle);
    tv.setText(item.getSnippet());

    mBtnDel=(Button)win.findViewById(R.id.tvLayClose);
    mBtnView=(Button)win.findViewById(R.id.tvLayAction);
    mBtnView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,DetailProperty.class);
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("detailId",mAlist);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
            dial.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mBtnDel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             dial.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

On clicking on view button just call ur activity with images and buttons....
 Hope it will useful for you...

Comment: hi, it will create a dialog which will take the focus off from maps.. I don't want that.. I want a view to be added like a overlay same as the marker, so that it will move around even when zoomed or panned. Thanks for the help anyway..

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

1) Add the mapview into a RelativeLayout
2) Add the View I want to place over the overlay into the same RelativeLayout
3) Override the "draw" method of the Overlay (using a CustomOverlay class that extends Overlay). Inside the method, call a handler that repositions the View